# ModuleNotFoundError Could not find module in path: '@emotion/weak-memoize'

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

I started with one of my projects as a watch-along from youtube and I myself was coding it in a Code-Sandbox.
Link to the sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-grass-wswrtd?file=/src/App.jsx

It is where I got the error:
`Could not find module in path: '@emotion/weak-memoize' relative to '/node_modules/@emotion/cache/dist/emotion-cache.cjs.dev.js'`

My package.json file is:
[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmU7g.png)

Even though i have the weak-memoize module in my dependencies, why am i still getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Change your weak-memoize version to 0.7.5.

This is a CodeSandBox bug, reverting back to a previous version of the module fixes the problem.

https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/6473